# WCF endpoint configuration: 2nd endpoint doesn't work at all, 1st endpoint doesn't seem affected by binding

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

In a WCF service hosted in IIS, I'm trying to set up multiple endpoints.  One for SOAP and one for SOAP12.  Per the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751515.aspx), I've edited `Web.config` like:

```
<services>
  <service name="MyNamespace.MyClass">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IContract" />
    <endpoint address="Endpoint2" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IContract" />
  </service>
</services>
```

This doesn't seem to have any effect. There is no answer on URL:

```
http://localhost:51454/MyClass.svc/Endpoint2
```

If I change `IContract` to `IContract2`, I get the error:

```
The service '/MyClass.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during 
compilation.
```

So the `Web.config` I'm editing is the one being used.

Changing the binding for the default address from `basicHttpBinding` to `wsHttpBinding` doesn't have any effect.  The WSDL stays the same.

The WSDL includes this bit, which seems to suggest that it's running using a generated binding:

```
<wsdl:service name="TapasSim">
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IContract" 
               binding="i0:BasicHttpBinding_IContract">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:51454/MyClass.svc"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Why does the WCF service not use the configuration from `Web.config`?
Why does WCF not listen on `/Endpoint2` with the SOAP12 binding?
Why does the default endpoint not change from `basicHttpBinding` to `wsHttpBinding`?

Comment: How are you generating the WSDL, using svcutil or using VS.

Comment: @Dhawalk: WCF generates the WSDL when you visit `MyClass.svc?wsdl`

Comment: can you use svcutil to generete the wsdl? I used VS to create service reference and was able to access both the endpoints from a client app

Comment: ok... never mind, I didnt see your answer below :)

Comment: @Dhawalk: Yeah, dumb typo.  Thanks for looking at it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the service name:

```
<service name="MyNamespace.MyClass">
```

The class name was wrong.  When you enter a wrong contract interface, WCF throws an error.  But a wrong class name is silently ignored.  That explains why it fell back on the default configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Try adling a base adress for the endpoint:

```
  <service name="namespace.Service">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:51454/myclass.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
```

// endpoint omnited

Or try adding a slash before the address:

endpoint address="/Endpoint2" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IContract"

Comment: Adding this has no effect at all, as far as I can see

Comment: Perhaps the config file is at the wrong location? I don't know what the right location is ón an IIS, but I would guess it has to be close to the .dll files. Usualy when I have this problem that is the reason.

Comment: If I change `IContract` to `IContract2`, the service shows an error message.  So I'm pretty sure it's in the right location.

Comment: Fair. Good test. I have one last guess - check the opdated answer

Comment: Tried that, no effect.  I've updated the question with a WDSL snippet

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN article is correct and there is nothing wrong in your configuration. I created a WCF client using VS and was able to successfully call using

```
http://localhost:51454/MyClass.svc/Endpoint2
```

Apparently, it does not appear as a valid url from browser. try consuming from a client using the second url and it should work